# How to configure preferred static IP on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter

Need some help here. I am having troubles attempting to configure 1 preferred static IP in my office network. Can anyone help me? Thanks.[image]

Comment: The `preferred` static IP is determined by the DHCP server - What's your server? What OS is your server?

Comment: Windows 2008...

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Configure a static ip adress for your box? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I am trying to access another network where my files are being kept. My main local static IP should be `192.168.1.13`. The files on the other server is `192.168.0.*` network.

Comment: Have you spoken with your organization IT about this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be areas in the DHCP/Autoconfiguration config of Windows Server 2008 that defines the preferred IP address(es) for a certain MAC address. Find the MAC address of your PC in question (in this case, `78-AC-C0-BF-31-54`), and search for that MAC in the DHCP leases. You *should* be able to change the preferred IP in that section. If you have subnets setup, you'll need to look in that specific subnet for the PC. If you want to change the IP to an IP that belongs in a different subnet, you'll need to move the PC to said subnet. Take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894461%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) documentation for some more information about the whole deal.